# convergence $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I check convergence of  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} $ ? 
If I want check necessary condition $u_n \rightarrow 0$ I need to do sth like that:
$$ u_n = 2^n \cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} = 2^n \cdot \left(\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n}\right)^2 $$ but now I can't write just 
$$ \left(\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n}\right)^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{e^2}$$ because I have $ 2^n $ part...
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmmm... $$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} \ne \left(\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n}\right)^2=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n} $$

Comment: Ahh.. My fail, your right, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test),

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{u_n}=\dfrac2{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n}=\dfrac2e<1$$

Comment: It is great idea! $\frac{1}{e} \in \left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{3} \right) $ so it is clearly under $1$. But how can I solve necessary condition? I can't use there root test